# why can not publish in unity 2018.2.15f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I have some errors that it attached, i can not  android build in unity 2018.2.15f1
what is happen?

> c:/pogram files/java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

can you sent "unity preferences"-> "external Tools" ss?

Comment: what? do you want  " perferences" photo ?